# How to convert this for-loop with a comparison into a list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm trying to get better at using list comprehension and this code works for the purpose I'm using it for (code challenge) but I want to use a list comprehension and understand why it works.

```
j = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    if (a[i] >= 0):
        a[i] = ans[j]
        j += 1
```

I have tried

```
lst = [x for (i,x) in enumerate(a) if x >= 0]
```

but obviously I'm misunderstanding something here because it didn't work.

Comment: what is `ans[j]` ? Is `ans` a list?

Comment: The main problem using a list comp here is that `j` is conditionally advanced. There is no easy way to manage it independently in the comprehension.

Comment: @JoeFerndz yes, it is the list thats being manipulated (sorta) but yes its a list

Comment: @DeepSpace would it be possible if j=0 stayed outside the list comp?

Comment: @Keyeric You'd still need to advance `j` somehow. You can define a function that advances it and returns the value `ans[j]`, but at this point you might as well leave the code as it is

Comment: List comprehensions are *for creating lists*. You aren't creating a list with your code, so using a list comprehension isn't really something that would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code with the explanation of the algorithm:

```
j = 0                    # set the "pointer" on `ans` to the start of `ans`
for i in range(len(a)):  # for every element `e` of `a`
    if (a[i] >= 0):      # if `e` is positive
        a[i] = ans[j]    # replace it by the current element of `ans`
        j += 1           # and advance the "pointer" on `ans`.
```

Basically, you iterate over `a` and when you find a positive number, you replace it with the next element of `ans`. Let's try with an example:

```
a = [-1, 2, -3, 5, 7, -9]
ans = [10, 20, 30, 40]
 
...
         
print(a)
# [-1, 10, -3, 20, 30, -9]
```

If you want to use a list comprehension, you have to create the list containing, for each element of `a`, either the next element of `ans` if the element is positive, or the element itself. And then assign the new list to `a`. It's pretty simple:

```
a = [ans.pop(0) if e >= 0 else e for e in a]
print(a)
# [-1, 10, -3, 20, 30, -9]
```

Obviously, if you don't want to consume `ans`, you can make a copy using:

```
temp = list(ans)
a = [e if e<0 else temp.pop(0) for e in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are conditionally advancing through `ans`, you'll need to use an iterator or an equivalent traversal mechanism which will avoid destroying `ans` in the process (as ans.pop(0) would):

```
ans = [-2,-4,-7]
a   = [-1,1,-3,2,-5,-6,3,-8,-9]

a   = [ n if n<0 else next(ans_j) for ans_j in [iter(ans)] for n in a]

print(a)
[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]
```